# In Python, how do I check if a string has alphabets or numbers?

Tags: python, regex

If the string has an alphabet or a number, return true. Otherwise, return false.

I have to do this, right?

```
return re.match('[A-Z0-9]',thestring)
```

Comment: Helpful hint: don't ever jump to the conclusion that regular expressions are the only (or the best) way. Often there will be a better way.

Comment: would you like to return true if the string contains AT LEAST one letter or one number, or if the string contains ONLY letters or numbers ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`thestring.isalnum()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) method.

```
>>> '123abc'.isalnum()
True
>>> '123'.isalnum()
True
>>> 'abc'.isalnum()
True
>>> '123#$%abc'.isalnum()
>>> a = '123abc' 
>>> (a.isalnum()) and (not a.isalpha()) and (not a.isnumeric())
True
>>>
```

Comment: @Owalla I assume the `alnum` part of `isalnum()` stands for alphanumeric, which essentially means `contains letters or numbers`. Sounds as if Python has a built-in string method to do this test for you, so no need to use a regular expression.

Comment: @Owalla the inbuilt .isalbnum() method checks if the string is alphanumeric. Regex would be an overkill for this operation.

Comment: This answer is wrong for the question: "If the string has an alphabet or a number, return true. Otherwise, return false."
This answer shows how to check if ALL characters are alphanumeric.

Comment: Interesting quirk is that thestring.isalnum() returns true for non-standard alphanumeric chars e.g. superscripted ones as in this example: "5432¹".isalnum() == True. This may break your use case (as it did mine).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check if *ALL* characters are alphanumeric:

- `string.isalnum()` (as @DrTyrsa pointed out), or
- `bool(re.match('[a-z0-9]+$', thestring, re.IGNORECASE))`

If you want to check if *at least one* alphanumeric character is present:

```
import string
alnum = set(string.letters + string.digits)
len(set(thestring) & alnum) > 0
```

or

`bool(re.search('[a-z0-9]', thestring, re.IGNORECASE))`

Comment: My brief testing indicates that, as I expected, `[A-Za-z0-9]` is somewhat faster than `[a-z0-9]` plus the `re.IGNORECASE` flag. And it's definitely nicer. (However you do it, it's still in the vicinity of ten times as slow as `str.isalnum()`).

Comment: @Chris Morgan: Thanks for benchmarking! I'd go for `isalnum()` anyway if I'd want to check all characters. I just added the regex as the OP explicitly asked for it in a comment.

Comment: note `string.letters` is removed in Python 3, substitute `string.ascii_letters` instead

Answer (score 2):

It might be a while, but if you want to figure out if the string at at least 1 alphabet or numeral, we could use

re.match('.*[a-zA-Z0-9].*', yourstring)

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
stringsample.isalpha()
```

method?

Comment: Please re-read the question. They are looking for alpha-numeric. Also, a valid answer was already provided over two years ago. While contributions are always welcome, it is best not to resurrect old threads unless the response contributes something *significant* over the existing answers.